# Multiple data histogram in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have a problem with a multiple data histogram.

I have a list of array, that each contain a different number of values. I want a stacked histogram, and I do obtain it, but I would have expected the value to be stacked 'one after an other', meaning all the blues at the bottom of the histogram, all the cyan above the bleu ect. But my histogram mixes them together.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bins_1=[25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 130, 135, 140, 145, 150, 155, 160, 165, 170]
x=[array([ -17.39386525,   48.368168  ,   79.47025691,   81.56601668,
         89.18470488,   95.41711067,  100.        ,  101.37656251,
        101.66780064]), array([  74.01649726,   76.57421598,   83.82263397,  101.09723897,
        101.35599967,  106.20473323,  125.32481435]), array([  80.30799141,   80.69495682,   90.64266387,  100.59333806,
        110.92342467,  114.03759007]), array([  75.73950779,   82.78756325,   91.12237053,   99.16053347,
        102.75900509,  111.29184111,  112.53084035]), array([  90.76141555,   95.50630177,   98.47127058,  101.53835677,
        118.05901363,  121.97579472,  123.93998025]), array([ 84.83641744,  88.25589465,  88.73029233,  90.67304666,
        92.45594435,  94.53857766]), array([  90.02129774,   97.47537826,   98.1094508 ,  104.90845359,
        123.88128883]), array([  70.45117675,   86.58666341,   88.58116115,   96.40940807,
        108.82477152,  119.2192689 ,  121.29656905]), array([  85.41581466,   89.11517158,   99.48923389,  105.79105149,
        107.17832611,  109.12150105,  117.93740188]), array([  84.9374751 ,   86.59808353,   89.4279953 ,   89.62824778,
         95.06305366,   96.73698641,   97.22749937,   98.11341876,
        100.59178895,  105.20938707]), array([  59.80245368,   82.96922252,   96.88431443,   98.08075879,
         99.1774299 ,  101.28416133,  127.44875806]), array([  97.39841438,  101.87313756,  103.74805137,  110.38644243,
        110.73198861,  125.97443118,  134.71140893,  148.63492245]), array([  88.60244669,   99.29194404,   99.82668617,  105.2816237 ]), array([  91.31362803,   94.91830313,   97.50844764,  111.59560735]), array([  79.45212159,   80.56841471,   90.74986538,   92.88847337,
         94.9665391 ,  100.98072459,  101.80697666,  111.38101874,
        112.75886621]), array([  17.04198007,   97.23402024,  100.54257276,  113.17293093,
        114.26809621,  121.08638797,  123.64111202]), array([], dtype=float64)]
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x,bins_1,histtype='barstacked')#, stacked=True)#,facecolor='green')
plt.show()
```

[Here is an an example of result](http://s10.postimg.org/lsv7jive1/DV_tot.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

haha, the problem is that matplotlib is reusing colors. So the plot is working as you want, you just need more colors. here is my modification to your code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import array


bins_1=[25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 130, 135, 140, 145, 150, 155, 160, 165, 170]
x=[array([ -17.39386525,   48.368168  ,   79.47025691,   81.56601668,
     89.18470488,   95.41711067,  100.        ,  101.37656251,
    101.66780064]), array([  74.01649726,   76.57421598,   83.82263397,  101.09723897,
    101.35599967,  106.20473323,  125.32481435]), array([  80.30799141,   80.69495682,   90.64266387,  100.59333806,
    110.92342467,  114.03759007]), array([  75.73950779,   82.78756325,   91.12237053,   99.16053347,
    102.75900509,  111.29184111,  112.53084035]), array([  90.76141555,   95.50630177,   98.47127058,  101.53835677,
    118.05901363,  121.97579472,  123.93998025]), array([ 84.83641744,  88.25589465,  88.73029233,  90.67304666,
    92.45594435,  94.53857766]), array([  90.02129774,   97.47537826,   98.1094508 ,  104.90845359,
    123.88128883]), array([  70.45117675,   86.58666341,   88.58116115,   96.40940807,
    108.82477152,  119.2192689 ,  121.29656905]), array([  85.41581466,   89.11517158,   99.48923389,  105.79105149,
    107.17832611,  109.12150105,  117.93740188]), array([  84.9374751 ,   86.59808353,   89.4279953 ,   89.62824778,
     95.06305366,   96.73698641,   97.22749937,   98.11341876,
    100.59178895,  105.20938707]), array([  59.80245368,   82.96922252,   96.88431443,   98.08075879,
     99.1774299 ,  101.28416133,  127.44875806]), array([  97.39841438,  101.87313756,  103.74805137,  110.38644243,
    110.73198861,  125.97443118,  134.71140893,  148.63492245]), array([  88.60244669,   99.29194404,   99.82668617,  105.2816237 ]), array([  91.31362803,   94.91830313,   97.50844764,  111.59560735]), array([  79.45212159,   80.56841471,   90.74986538,   92.88847337,
     94.9665391 ,  100.98072459,  101.80697666,  111.38101874,
    112.75886621]), array([  17.04198007,   97.23402024,  100.54257276,  113.17293093,
    114.26809621,  121.08638797,  123.64111202]),]
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x,bins_1, histtype='bar', stacked=True, normed=1, color=['b','g','y','purple','pink','crimson','burlywood','chartreuse','magenta','firebrick','cyan','black','darkgoldenrod', 'gray','g','k' ])
plt.show()
```

notice that each color is specified.

```
color=['b','g','y','purple','pink','crimson','burlywood','chartreuse','magenta','firebrick','cyan','black','darkgoldenrod', 'gray','g','k' ]
```

if you want to verify that this is what is really happening, in your own code, set `cumulative=True` and you will see that the colors line up. only you dont want a cumulative graph, so specifying colors may be the best option at the time being.

**UPDATE:**
using mpltools (which you will need to download) you can do this a little easier.
to install, if linux just type `sudo pip install mpltools`

here is a workable example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
from mpltools import layout
from mpltools import color



bins_1=[25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 130, 135, 140, 145, 150, 155, 160, 165, 170]
x=[array([ -17.39386525,   48.368168  ,   79.47025691,   81.56601668,
     89.18470488,   95.41711067,  100.        ,  101.37656251,
    101.66780064]), array([  74.01649726,   76.57421598,   83.82263397,  101.09723897,
    101.35599967,  106.20473323,  125.32481435]), array([  80.30799141,   80.69495682,   90.64266387,  100.59333806,
    110.92342467,  114.03759007]), array([  75.73950779,   82.78756325,   91.12237053,   99.16053347,
    102.75900509,  111.29184111,  112.53084035]), array([  90.76141555,   95.50630177,   98.47127058,  101.53835677,
    118.05901363,  121.97579472,  123.93998025]), array([ 84.83641744,  88.25589465,  88.73029233,  90.67304666,
    92.45594435,  94.53857766]), array([  90.02129774,   97.47537826,   98.1094508 ,  104.90845359,
    123.88128883]), array([  70.45117675,   86.58666341,   88.58116115,   96.40940807,
    108.82477152,  119.2192689 ,  121.29656905]), array([  85.41581466,   89.11517158,   99.48923389,  105.79105149,
    107.17832611,  109.12150105,  117.93740188]), array([  84.9374751 ,   86.59808353,   89.4279953 ,   89.62824778,
     95.06305366,   96.73698641,   97.22749937,   98.11341876,
    100.59178895,  105.20938707]), array([  59.80245368,   82.96922252,   96.88431443,   98.08075879,
     99.1774299 ,  101.28416133,  127.44875806]), array([  97.39841438,  101.87313756,  103.74805137,  110.38644243,
    110.73198861,  125.97443118,  134.71140893,  148.63492245]), array([  88.60244669,   99.29194404,   99.82668617,  105.2816237 ]), array([  91.31362803,   94.91830313,   97.50844764,  111.59560735]), array([  79.45212159,   80.56841471,   90.74986538,   92.88847337,
     94.9665391 ,  100.98072459,  101.80697666,  111.38101874,
    112.75886621]), array([  17.04198007,   97.23402024,  100.54257276,  113.17293093,
    114.26809621,  121.08638797,  123.64111202]),]
n_lines = len(x)
color.cycle_cmap(n_lines, cmap='cool')
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x,bins_1, histtype='bar', stacked=True, normed=1) 
plt.show()
```

and [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html)  is a list of cmaps you can choose from and [here](http://tonysyu.github.io/mpltools/auto_examples/color/plot_cycle_cmap.html#example-color-plot-cycle-cmap-py) is the documentation this answer is derived from.

this is with `color.cycle_cmap(n_lines, cmap='Dark2')`

[image]

Comment: Yep that was it !Thank you. Hopefully one day I will stop asking stupid questions ;)

Comment: Not stupid at all, your code worked the way it was suppose to, it was a package default setting. those are the "bugs" that can cause the most frustration haha. I actually enjoyed looking at the answers because that second answer I am implementing right now into a code at work. much more pythonic than the long list meathod.  enjoy your pythoning!

Comment: oh, and feel free to mark the question as answered by clicking the checkmark, this way others can benefit from the answer too. :)